# Android how to remove padding left for action bar icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I have an action bar which has an icon

I want the icon to be exactly in the left of screen, i mean without any padding .

is that possible?

i already found this answer [remove padding around action bar left icon on Android 4.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026007/remove-padding-around-action-bar-left-icon-on-android-4-0) but i don't know if this large code is what I need. and in face that answer removes the padding for the action bar icon in all the application, i need just for a specific activity.

Comment: The link you gave has a right solution. He first explained how the internal code in android works. You can switch to the solution part of it which is at the bottom.