# Change the space between action bar icon and the left side of the screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change the distance between the left side of the device screen and the action bar icon. I want to totally remove this space ... 
[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

I have tried to put margin or padding inside the action bar customised style I have created but nothing...

```
<style name="BCPActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_third_level_menu</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/BCPTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:height">55dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">-2dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I found solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026007/remove-padding-around-action-bar-left-icon-on-android-4-0

Answer (score 0):

try

`<item name="paddingLeft">0dp</item>`