# Android Lollipop, AppCompat ActionBar custom view doesn't take up whole screen width

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-5.0-lollipop

So, I just updated my codebase to Lollipop, and I'm having issues with the Action Bar.  I'm using AppCompat and ActionBarActivity, and inflating a custom view.  It seems that the custom view no longer takes up the whole width of the screen, leaving a thin strip on the left

[image: Building with 19]
Way it used to look

[image: Building with 21]
Way it looks now

This is the code I'm using to set up the Action Bar.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if(actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_content_search_custom_view);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    // actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(null);
    TextView title = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
    title.setText(R.string.youtube);
    ImageView back = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit**

Taking out the custom view and changing the background now takes up the whole width.  So the issue is, how can we make a CustomView take up the whole width of the ActionBar?

Comment: If you temporarily comment out the custom view parts, does it behave better? If not, I'd lean towards this perhaps coming from your theme.

Comment: I removed the custom view, and set it's background as the background drawable of the ActionBar and the background does take up the whole width now

Comment: You might peek at your activity in Hierarchy View, both with and without the custom view, and see if you can determine what layout rules are shifting as a result of the custom view. It's possible that this is a bug in the new `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: Looks to me that is the place reserved for up `ImageView`. Try disabling it for starters.

Comment: I am facing this problem as well.

Comment: Hi, it seems this is a good solution to have the custom view take the whole width.  I was experiencing it not expanding, even with layout weights set. see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20794736/581574

Comment: @StevieKideckel  how u resolved your issue i m also facing same ? in actionbar in api level 21

Comment: The chosen answer worked for me, have you tried it out?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by the latest changes to the `ActionBar` in the recent `appcompat-v7` update.
It seems like that there are significant changes to how you should handle action bars.

I faced the same issue and after reading the [`ActionBar` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html), and especially the following quote I found a solution.

> Beginning with Android L (API level 21), the action bar may be represented by any Toolbar widget within the application layout. The application may signal to the Activity which Toolbar should be treated as the Activity's action bar. Activities that use this feature should use one of the supplied .NoActionBar themes, set the windowActionBar attribute to false or otherwise not request the window feature.

The way I see it, the `AppCompat` themes were changed and on one hand seemed to break a few things but provide much more flexibility on the other.
I recommend following these steps:

1. Use `.NoActionBar` style in your activity as described in the above quote
2. Add a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` to your Activity layout
3. Set the `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` attribute. **This is the main issue with the margin that you describe in your question**

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It's usually recommended that you do that in a separate layout file and use `include` in your activity layout so you will only need to customize the Toolbar in one place if used in multiple activities

```
<include layout="@layout/view_action_bar" />
```

4. Use `findViewById` and `setSupportActionBar` in your Activity `onCreate` to `signal to the Activity which Toolbar should be treated as the Activity's action bar`

```java
Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
```

5. Once you do that, all actions added in `onCreateOptionsMenu` will be added to the toolbar and it will be treated as the activity action bar.
6. Further customize the Toolbar as desired (Add child views etc.)

Comment: I am trying to use Toolbar with navigation drawer however I am getting error `Error inflating class fragment`

Comment: All the relevant code is shared on the answer. Looks like you should start a new question for your case as it seems like a different problem.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem by replacing actionbar with Toolbar.

Comment: Thanks so much! You saved my day! But I'm still looking for a way to put the bottom divider of action bars in my toolbar. Actually, I don't know if it is really a divider in the action bar. It is normally bellow the action bar and it is really a shadow over the content. Any idea?

Comment: You shouldn't use explicit package names in the namespace declarations. Use `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Do you add the custom view to the new Toolbar or by using actionbar.setCustomView()?

Comment: There is no need for `setCustomView`. Just build a layout file with the widgets you want to include in your toolbar (e.g. add child views to the layout file described in section 3 of the answer)

Comment: Not able to get click event in onOptionsItemSelected with setSupportActionBar(actionBar);, can you please provide solution for this.

Comment: I added following in toolbar                                         app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"                                                                     and it is working now!

Comment: This only works when extending `AppCompatActivity`, as `setSupportActionBar(ToolBar)` is not available in a regular `Activity`. Any workaround without having to use `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: @Muzikant thanks for your answer. when I put my sutom action bar i doesn't have shadow as normal action bar. how or where I can implement it to have shadow?

Comment: I am supporting the 14th API version and sadly it does not work. Minimum supported version is 21. Any work around?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saves my life. The tonic code is 
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"

Comment: This was killing me:
    
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"

10xs

Answer (score 51):

Instead of doing so much of work as mentioned by [Muzikant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454325/1576416) and like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29058430/1576416)

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_home, null);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomView);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) mCustomView.getParent();//first get parent toolbar of current action bar 
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);// set padding programmatically to 0dp
```

You have to add only the last two lines of code to solve your problem.

I hope this might help you and anyone else.

> **UPDATE:** After making some research on it, i found that this solution will not work in some cases. The left side gap (HOME or BACK) will be removed with this but the right side gap (MENU) will remain as is. Below is the solution in these cases.

```
View v = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
LayoutParams lp = v.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
v.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Add these four lines to above code, so that the right side gap is also removed from support action bar.

Comment: thanks! thanks! the last 2 lines was what ive been looking for!

Comment: Where do we add these lines? After the Toolbar part?

Comment: @summers yes add them immediately after toolbar code.

Answer (score 31):

I think you can also do that in styles. try this. tested it on kitkat

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/AppThemeToolbar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar" >
  <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This answer is wrong: android:contentInsetStart requires API level 21 (current min is 14)

Comment: But, idiom very good! You need write style separately for api 21 and old versions.

Comment: This is the correct answer to remove the left margin if you are still using the default action bar.

Comment: This works indeed!  With the latest version of the support lib, I think you don't need to declare the attributes twice (the android: ones are not necessary).

Comment: I've been searching for this problem and when I've found your answer I see that I already upvoted it! So thanks twice.

Comment: Didn't work for me, still have the left/right padding.

Answer (score 8):

None of the other answers worked for me, so I took a look at the actual AppCompat v7 styles, found [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml).

If you look at the Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar style, it has:

```
<item name="contentInsetStart">@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material</item>
<item name="contentInsetEnd">@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material</item>
```

So obviously we just need to override those properties in our own action bar style:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
</style>
```

This worked great for me, hope it helps others too.

Comment: Yep, as the chosen answer states, the key is the contentInsetStart and contentInsetEnd attributes of the ActionBar/Toolbar.  It's valid to define your own style, but you can also set them to 0dp on the attributes of the Toolbar in your xml

Answer (score 1):

After much beating my head against the monitor, this worked for me

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) actionBar.getCustomView().getParent();
        toolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(0);
        toolbar.setContentInsetEndWithActions(0);
        toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
        toolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The getCustomView().getParent() is what did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem today as well, then I found out I was having `res/values-v21/styles.xml` inside my project which was generated automatically by Android Studio and that's the cause.

Why?

Because my `res/values-v21/styles.xml`'s content was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

And my `res/values/styles.xml` contained something like:

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Then when I ran my app on Lollipop, the `res/values-v21/styles.xml` was used, and that caused exact problem that OP had.
So I came to a simple fix is just deleting:

```
    <style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>
```

in `res/values-v21/styles.xml`

Answer (score 0):

to the point:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
                actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) actionBar.getCustomView().getParent();
                    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
                    toolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

make sure importing the right toolbar - `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

Answer (score 0):

Write these two line in addition with your code

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)viewActionBar.getParent();
toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still having this issue, along with the setting the insets to 0, also change the padding of the toolbar to 0.

```
supportActionBar?.customView?.apply {
            (parent as Toolbar?)?.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0)
            (parent as Toolbar?)?.setContentInsetsRelative(0,0)
            (parent as Toolbar?)?.setPadding(0)
        }
```