# AppCompat ActionBar custom view doesn't take up whole screen width

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I updated my codebase to Lollipop, and I'm having issues with the Action Bar. I'm using AppCompat and inflating a custom view. It seems that the custom view no longer takes up the whole width of the screen, leaving a thin strip on the left
[image]
How can i remove that? 
Tried all standart ways for older verions to fix that, but nothing helps...
Need some help.

P.S. anyway i **can't use toolbar**, i have to use actionBar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433409/android-lollipop-appcompat-actionbar-custom-view-doesnt-take-up-whole-screen-w

Comment: i CAN'T use toolbar, that post is not valid for me

Answer (score 0):

I've met this error. Replace the current appcompat version with the older one