# How to have the options menu over the custom toolbar?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I have a similar problem as found [on this specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433409/android-lollipop-appcompat-actionbar-custom-view-doesnt-take-up-whole-screen-w).

I'm using a Toolbar from the v7 support library, and a custom layout. If I have no options menu, I have a result similar to what OP has on the question linked above:

[image: Result with no options menu]

However if I have an options menu, it shifts the toolbar a little bit to the left (start). I would like to have it *over* the toolbar.

[image: Result with an options menu]

Is it possible? The only way I could hack it is by adding a negative right (end) margin to the toolbar layout, however this moves the menu *outside* of the screen…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, the whole Toolbar contained several views, so they had to share the width with the action menu.

Now instead I wrapped the Toolbar and the other views in a container (a `FrameLayout`), so that they overlap without sharing the width. I just need to be careful with the margin at the top so that the other views don't overlap with action icons.