# Black area is shown at left side in custom Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I found answer here :
[Android Lollipop, AppCompat ActionBar custom view doesn't take up whole screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433409/android-lollipop-appcompat-actionbar-custom-view-doesnt-take-up-whole-screen-w)

I'm using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and setting custom layout in actionbar, But black area is displayed on the left side of actionbar.

[image]

This is the code of custom layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/color_red" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/actionbarBack_backButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/back_transparent_white"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_back_white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbarBack_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Some text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="10dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code, how I'm using in activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_back_title);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**onStart:**

```
@Override 
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Already mentioned in onStart, I've added the code. Kindly have a look above.