# Remove left padding on custom action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

First I know this is a duplicate question, but none of the answers solved my issue.

Here is my current code:

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:background="@color/article_background">
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/filter"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:id="@+id/filters"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/tc_logo"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/logo" />

<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/menu_button"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:id="@+id/options"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

And there is a left padding showing.

I tried the following suggestions from Stack Overflow:

- I tried setting a custom actionbar style in themes with zero padding.
- I tried with relative and linear layout as the custom layout.
- I tried setting custom actionbar icon in themes and enabling onHomeUp to display a one px image..
- I tried layout gravity and gravity to fill_horizontal but didn't work.

No matter what I do, it still shows up.

Comment: I finally went with negative margin of 14 dp....but not the answer still.

Comment: I am still facing this issue.Do you have another solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no...stack is full of various answers but for some reason none of them worked for me, neither did combinations of them. I did find that this hack od -14dp margin when set in styles.xml works across all devices, screens, densities...but still i would prefer a normal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and nothing helped, until I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026007/remove-padding-around-action-bar-left-icon-on-android-4-0).

### TL;DR

1. Have the Actionbar to display its up arrow, by calling `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`.
2. Create a style based on your apps theme in "values-v14" (these will
   apply to SDK Version 14 and above).
3. have this item in the new style: `<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>`. This will cause the up to disappear, but the padding the icon had will be gone.

Comment: Interesting i will try this out and let you know if it works.

Comment: Nope, didnt work. Event though i put @null for indicator in my action bar style, the arrow is shown.

Comment: Merde!
Can you post a code digest (Code sample, reproduction or something) to here, or better yet, to GitHub? 
I'll clone and see what's up...