# Spacing between edge of screen and ActionBar logo

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Basically, I want to make sure my UI elements (TextViews, Buttons, etc) are left aligned with the `ActionBar` logo. My idea was to try to find out the left spacing between the edge of the screen and the left side of the logo (shown highlighted in blue in the attached image), and use this value as the left margin for the UI elements in my Activity, but I've been unable to get this value.

[image]

So, how can I get the value of this margin? Or, is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the standards for defining paddings as described in the Android Design documents on [d.android.com](http://d.android.com). [This](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) page gives a good example of how your layout must be structured in terms of paddings between elements.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already gone through that part of the Android documentation and it doesn't specify the specific Actionbar padding values I'm looking for.

Comment: The point is that you should just use the standard padding values and not the ActionBar padding.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but sometimes clients want what clients want :)

Answer (score 0):

You check these answers . Custom layout for the action bar worked for me to change this padding and you can also get padding value.

[remove padding around action bar left icon on Android 4.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026007/remove-padding-around-action-bar-left-icon-on-android-4-0)